# Show that $\lambda_1 = \min \{ Q(u) \mid \|u\| = 1 \}$ and $\lambda_m = \max \{ Q(u) \mid \|u\| = 1 \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V$ a vector space over $K$ and $Q(u) = \langle u, Tu \rangle$ a quadratic form. $T$ is a symmetric operator. The eigenvalues of $T$ are sorted by size $\lambda_1 < \dots < \lambda_m$.

How can I show that

$$\lambda_1 = \min \lbrace Q(u) | \ \|u\| = 1 \rbrace$$ and $$\lambda_m = \max \lbrace Q(u) | \ \|u\| = 1 \rbrace$$

Comment: This is an instance of the [Courant Fischer theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).  Are you aware of the [spectral theorem?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the spectral theorem, we have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ associated with $\lambda_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n$.  We want to show that $\lambda_1 = \min\{Q(u):\|u\| = 1\}$.  First, note that setting $u = v_1$ yields $Q(u) = \lambda_1$, so it suffices to show that $Q(u) \geq \lambda_1$ whenever $\|u\| = 1$.

Take an arbitrary such $u$.  Write $u = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$, noting that $\|u\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2 = 1$. Verify that
$$
Q(u) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i |a_i|^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_1 |a_i|^2 = \lambda_1
$$
In order to verify the opposite inequality, apply the above to $-Q(u) = \langle u, (-T)u \rangle$.

Comment: This is, of course, a terse summary of the proof.  Let me know if any of these steps are unclear.

Comment: Of course, this assumes that either $K = \mathbb R$ or $K = \mathbb C$